# U2 Toolkit for .NET - RPC Failed, An established connection was aborted [errorcode=81009]

Tags: u2, universe, u2netdk

I am using the U2 Toolkit for .NET to access our Universe system from MS SSIS.  This has been working great while running some investigation tests on several files returning less than 200k rows of data.  On my latest run, using a new file where the query returns approx 800k rows of data I am getting the following error:

> Load SO:Error: U2.Data.Client.U2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [0]  [U2][UCINET-UO]WIN32 API Error:10053An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine[Rocket U2][UCINET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81009] The RPC failed Error in Socket Send and dataLength:36 Inner Exception:Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. Inner Exception:WIN32 API Error:10053An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine[Rocket U2][UCINET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81009] The RPC failed Error in Socket Send and dataLength:36 ---> U2.Data.Client.Ucinet.UciException:  [U2][UCINET-UO]WIN32 API Error:10053An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine[Rocket U2][UCINET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81009] The RPC failed Error in Socket Send and dataLength:36 Inner Exception:Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. Inner Exception:WIN32 API Error:10053An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine[Rocket U2][UCINET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81009] The RPC failed Error in Socket Send and dataLength:36
>      at U2.Data.Client.Ucinet.UciStatement.g()   at U2.Data.Client.Ucinet.UciStatement.Close()   at U2.Data.Client.U2DataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)   at U2.Data.Client.U2PoolManager.HandleUnknownErrors(String strFncMsg, Exception exception, Boolean bThrow)   at U2.Data.Client.U2DataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)   at U2.Data.Client.U2Command.k()   at U2.Data.Client.U2Command.CloseFromConnection()   at U2.Data.Client.U2Connection.DisposeClose()   at U2.Data.Client.U2Connection.Close()   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.CloseManagedConnection(Object managedConnection)   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager.ReleaseConnection(Object connection)   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.ReleaseConnections()   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostReleaseConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

This connection was working great until used in this "Data Flow" task.

From the unirpcservices file the timeouts are set as follows:

> uvnet /usr/ibm/uv/bin/uvnetd * TCP/IP 0 3600 uvdrsrv
>   /usr/ibm/uv/bin/uvdrsrvd * TCP/IP 0 3600 uvserver
>   /usr/ibm/uv/bin/uvsrvd * TCP/IP 0 3600 uvcs
>   /usr/ibm/uv/bin/uvapi_server * TCP/IP 0 3600 defcs
>   /usr/ibm/uv/bin/uvapi_server * TCP/IP 0 3600 uvfilefix
>   /usr/ibm/uv/bin/uvfilefix_server * TCP/IP 0 3600

here is my connections string:

> Server=10.0.0.237;User
>   ID=bicopy;Database=NSA;ServerType=Universe;FirstNormalForm=False;
>   Connection Manager: ADO.NET:U2.Data.Client.U2Connection,
>   U2.Data.Client, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9ab9148678f4f448

The query timeout is set to -1 and `rpcServiceType` is defcs.

This error happens after approx 10 min.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please increase time-out in Connection String?
For example :

ServerType=universe;ConnectTimeout=720

Comment: No, increasing the timeout did not resolve the problem.  Our DBA flushed a cache and that seems to clear it up, at least temporarily.

Comment: Generally 10053 and 10054 errors are related with “TIMEOUT” or “SERVER GONE”.
“TIMEOUT” means execution is taking more time than ConnectTimeOut connection string parameter. By default, it is 5 minutes (300 seconds). In your case, it takes approximately 10 minutes. So should specify around 20 minutes (ConnectTimeOut=1200).

“SERVER GONE” means for some reason, there is problem in UCI Server (uvsrd.exe is not running or crash)

You can lodge issue with U2 Support if you see this problem again.